# Are [nested-queries] and [nested-query] just sub types of [subquery]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[nested-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-queries) and [nested-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-query) have the same meaning, although neither of them is too popular.

I don't have a high enough score in either to suggest a synonym in the tag page, but combining them seems like a no-brainer.
Moreover, as Dharman suggested in the comments, both of them should probably just be synonyms of the considerably more popular [subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subquery) tag.

Comment: Do we need either one of them? Aren't these just synonyms of [tag:subquery]?

Comment: @Dharman good point! Didn't even remember that one existed. I guess both of them should be synonyms of the more popular [subquery] tag. I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Have you reviewed enough questions from both tags to confirm that they are indeed asking about subqueries? Because I have not done this yet.

Comment: @Dharman not exhaustively (there are several hundred there), but went over the three top pages, and they all seem to refer to the same thing. There are of course some questions that are mis-tagged in [nested-query] (i.e., aren't about database queries even though the tag info explicitly states that's the purpose of the tag), and [nested-queries] doesn't have a tag info, so technically everything goes... but except for some outliers, the brunt of the questions suggest all three tags mean the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merged [nested-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-queries) into [nested-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-query) and synonimized both to [subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subquery).

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround on this!

Comment: I think it was pretty obvious that both tags referred to the same thing. If there are objections to the synonym, it can still be undone.